# ExtJS3 Virtual Keyboard plugin throws a exception in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, pdf-generation, virtual-keyboard

I had used virtual keyboard plugin available [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?47025-Ext.ux.VirtualKeyboard-and-its-plugin) in Ext JS 3 :

It does not seem to be working with Ext JS 4 . I have changed VirtualKeyboard.js file & it looks as follwing, problem is BackSpace gives me an error : 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Thrown while executing `dom.value.substr(0, dom.value.length - 1)`

Here is modified VirtualKeyboard.js  : 
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?147963-Extjs-4-virtual-keyboard-plugin

Comment: I don't understand how the VirtualKeyboard is relevant for generating a PDF from an ExtJs form.
Please clarify your question. Do you need a solution for a virtual keyboard on ExtJS4?

Comment: For the PDF part of your question: There is no Plugin to create a PDF on client side if you just using JavaScript. There should be only one question per post, therefore I've edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making changes in the original virtual keyboard file, use the sencha provided, Ext JS 3 to Ext JS 4 migration pack. This will allow the you to run Ext 3 code under Ext JS 4. You can use this pack until the original author of the virtual keyboard provides a patch for ext js 4. Using this pack does not have a drastic effect on the performance of the application because of the increased indirection.

You can download the migration pack from [here](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-3-to-4-migration/).

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

To fix you error use Firebug and debug the content of your `dom` variable. It seems that either your `keyboardTarget` variable has a wrong value or you need to fix your value accessor then you should just select the `el` and access it with `el.getValue()` (untested!)